# Other ways of performing modulo operation

Tags: javascript, performance, modulo

Some time ago I've seen somewhere a trick to perform modulo operation using bit operators. But now I cannot in any way perform proper operation. Anyone knows how to do it ? From what I remember it was faster than using %.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Performance_issues - for powers of 2.

Comment: Nice question, I checked here: http://jsperf.com/js-modulo and the answers down seem good!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "trick" is to binary `AND` a value with 1. Any odd number must have the first bit set to 1.

So

```
var foo = 7;

if( foo & 1 ) { // true
}
```

Using a bitwise AND has a better performance in almost all platforms / browsers.

```
for(var loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
    if( loop & 1 ) {
        console.log('I am ', loop, ' and I am odd!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do the modulo of 2^k (a power of 2) by ANDing your value with (2^k)-1.