# Project Euler - Trying to better my Javascript through P.E., Stuck on number 2

Tags: javascript

Project Euler, problem 2:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

my code so far:

```
var fib = [1,2];

var x = 0,
    y = 1,
    z = 0,
    ans = 0;

while (true){
    z = fib[x++] + fib[y++];
    fib.push(z);

    if ( !(z & 1) ) {
        console.log(z + ' is even');
        ans += z;
    };

    if(z > 4000000){
        break;
    }
}

console.log('answer = ' + ans);
```

and my console prints out:

```
8 is even
34 is even
144 is even
610 is even
2584 is even
10946 is even
46368 is even
196418 is even
832040 is even
3524578 is even

answer = 4613730
```

Does someone see the problem with my code? I've done the first 10 or so problems using Java a while back, but I don't remember having problems on this one.

Comment: Hint: Look at the first 10 numbers given in the problem, and consider what output you would expect from those...

Comment: Just wondering, what not use the modulus `%` operator to check if a number is even?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Mainly for performance, specifically this is where I got that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572670/other-ways-of-performing-modulo-operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [**Daniel** said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141374/1615483), you're forgetting the first `2`, it may be better to write your initial values as `[1, 0]` or use a generator like this

```
var fib = (function () {
    var a = 1, b = 0, c = 0;
    return function () {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        return b = c;
    };
}());

var i, t = 0;
while ((i = fib()) < 4000000) {
    if ((i & 1) === 0) {
        t += i;
    }
}
t; // 4613732
```

---

The *Fibonacci sequence* actually starts `1, 1, 2, 3`..

Comment: A couple questions: first, I'm used to java where each time a method is called, the variable values in that method are reset. That doesn't hold true in Javascript? Also, why the triple equal signs? Since we are dealing with primitives, there would be no issue with just a double equals right?

Comment: Also, I copied and pasted your code and it returns the same answer my code does when you set ans = 2 --- I lied, I posted in a different question, which is why I got the wrong answer. My apologies

Comment: @yazan _Java_ and _JavaScript_ are different languages; I'm not sure how closure/scope work in _Java_, but in _JavaScript_ these variables are not reset because they're in an ancestor closure of the function `fib`. Triple equals signs (strict equality) were not necessary, but I always use them over double equals (abstract equality) except in special circumstances

Comment: @yazan my code produces `4613732`. I'm not sure what change you've made

Comment: :D Well I figured Java and JS are different lol. For the ===, do you primarily use it over the == as a safety net, or is there an inherent benefit?

Comment: @yazan I don't like that it does type conversions, it makes it feel inconsistent to me `"" == 0; // true` and `" " == 0; // true`, but `"" == " "; // false`. Back on topic of the answer - if performance is important to you, you can move the function body into the loop (and order the condition slightly differently) to save yourself function overheads

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the first "2"

*Maybe setting z initial to 2 helps ...*

**EDIT:**
I was wrong!
setting **ans** initial to 2 helps

Comment: No, setting z initially to 2 doesn't help.

Comment: I was just going to say that, though I would assume thats one of the problems. good call though